# How to reference something in @Value from an other @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have a number of `@Value` properties in my spring bean. Most of the time only the first one is set in the properties file. The others should derieve their values from the first one with sensible defaults if not overwritten.

Unfortunately this only works with one level. If I try to reference a property with 2 level its not finding it any more.

```
@Component("pvcConfiguration")
public class PvcConfiguration {

    @Value(value = "${com.abc.pvc.path}")
    private Path path;
    
    // one level works fine
    @Value(value = "${com.abc.pvc.ftp.path:${com.abc.pvc.path}/ftp}")
    private Path ftpPath;

    // two levels do not work
    @Value(value = "${com.abc.pvc.etc.path:${com.abc.pvc.ftp.path}/etc}")
    private Path etcPath;

}
```

Error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.abc.pvc.ftpPath' in value "com.abc.pvc.etcPath:${ch.sbb.infop.pvc.ftp.path}/etc"
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Value(value = "${com.abc.pvc.path}")
private Path path;

// one level works fine
@Value(value = "${com.abc.pvc.ftp.path:${com.abc.pvc.path}/ftp}")
private Path ftpPath;

// two levels do not work
@Value(value = "${com.abc.pvc.etc.path:${com.abc.pvc.ftp.path:${com.abc.pvc.path}}/etc}")
private Path etcPath;
```

you not set placeholder com.abc.pvc.ftp.path, when you set ftpPath
Guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: That does not work for me. I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.abc.pvc.ftp.path' in value "#{'${com.abc.pvc.ftp.path}:${com.abc.pvc.path}/ftp'}"
`

Comment: @BetaRide, yes,you'll need to add those to your properties/yaml.

Comment: @BetaRide for me it's work, maybe you not add this property (com.abc.pvc.ftp.path/com.abc.pvc.path)?

Comment: The wole thing does not make sense if com.abc.pvc.ftp.path must be in the properties file. In most cases only com.abc.pvc.path should be there and the other values should set their defaults based on this.

Comment: yes, that works if that contains the entire value, but seeing as that is not the case, that's not how it works

Comment: @BetaRide i am edit answer, this you mean?

Comment: Yes. Looks ugly but works.